# Computing Local Evidence for Bayesian Networks

Tags: bayesian, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I am reading through Kevin Murphy's "Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective" book. I'm interested in understanding how to do exact bayesian inference over a tree structure, as discussed in Chapter 20. I understand the formulas at a basic level, but I am not sure how to compute beliefs of nodes using the belief propagation algorithm.

Murphy defines the bottom up belief state as:

$bel_t^-(x_t) \triangleq p(x_t|\textbf{v}_t^-) = \frac{1}{Z_t}\psi_t(x_t) \prod_{c\in ch(t)} m_{c\rightarrow t}^-(x_t)$,

where $\psi_t(x_t) \propto p(x_t|\textbf{v}_t)$ is the local evidence. Suppose I have  the following tent-structured graph of binary variables: $A \rightarrow B, A \rightarrow C$, and I've made the observation that $A = 1$.

My question is, how am I supposed to calculate this local evidence for the other nodes, for example node $C$? We only have $p(A), p(B|A),$ and $p(C|A)$ specified in the conditional probability tables. I know that $\textbf{v}$ is a vector of all observations in the graph, but I'm not sure what $\textbf{v}_t$ really is, let alone how to calculate $p(x_t|\textbf{v}_t)$.

Thanks for your help and clarifications!